# Optimization of multiplexer to improve performance

Tags: c, circuit

I am currently working on a school project that is a circuit simulator. One of the components to this circuit can be a multiplexer, which has n inputs, log2(n) selectors, and 1 output.

The way I determine which output is needed is by doing the following: 
Generate (# of selectors) bit gray code table, and loop through the table and compare to the values of the selectors. Whichever row is a match is the output needed.

However, for larger multiplexers (16:1, 32:1), this becomes quite slow. Is there a more efficient way to get the output needed without having to compare every single possible graycode possibility?

Comment: Binary search or hash table? Could probably get better answer if you can show the table you're searching.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

So you wish to construct a unique number in the range [0, 2<sup>*n*</sup>) (the index of the selected input) from *n* inputs (the selector signals) which are in the range [0, 1].

That's [binary code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number)!

Assign one of the selector signals the value 1, the next signal the value 2, then 4, and so on. Add them together. Select the corresponding numbered input.

```
unsigned selectedInput = 0;
if (selector1) selectedInput += 1; /* or |= */
if (selector2) selectedInput += 2;
if (selector3) selectedInput += 4;
```

And so on. In the generic case:

```
unsigned selectedInput = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < selectorCount; ++i)
    if (selectors[i]) selectedInput |= 1u << i;
```

Comment: im not exactly sure that i understand, lets say the inputs are 0,0,1,0, and the selectors are 0 and 1 since 0,1 is the second row of possible gray code, then the output should be 0, but im not sure how I see that from your answer

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite clear what clarification you're asking for. Gray code has nothing to do with this solution. Did I miss something in your problem description?

Comment: Using an example with inputs 0,0,1,0, and the selectors being 0 and 1, I dont see how to get the answer with your implementation

Comment: Put the input values in an array. Calculate the selected input using the logic above. Return the input value at the calculated array index.

Comment: in the case where the inputs are 0,0, 1, 0, and the selectors are 1 and 0, the output should be the last 0, however, with your logic, the answer should be the second 0?

Comment: Why do you think the output should be the last zero? Maybe you haven't clearly explained the requirements.